# Exibir calculo de frete na pagina de cada produto WP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, web-service

Como fazer para que o campo de calculo de frete seja exibido na tela de apresentação do produto alguém conheçe algum plugin que eu posso usar ou que tenha o algum exemplo pronto?

Comment: Essa função foi removida nas versões mais novas

Answer (score 2):

Essa opção foi **removida** na versão 3.0.0 do plugin, lançada em 26/06/2016.

### Edit:

Desenvolvi um plugin que implementa novamente esta função.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Repositório do WordPress:
https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-correios-calculo-de-frete-na-pagina-do-produto/

Github: https://github.com/Luc45/WooCommerce-Correios-Calculo-de-Frete-na-Pagina-do-Produto/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Existe essa função nativa no plugin dos correios `Versão 2.3.0` ou maior.

Para conseguir acessa-la, basta seguir o caminho:

No painel admin > woocommerce > Configurações > Entrega > Correios.

Dentro dessa página, há uma opção:

"Enable product shipping simulator"
Basta seleciona-la.

[image: Imagem com print da tela]

Anexei a foto do painel admin caso não ache a opção.